# how to re-create the .Trash file in ubuntu server

Tags: server, trash, rm

I recently deleted the `.Trash` file in Ubuntu server using the command

```
alias rm="mv -t ~/.Trash"
```

and now I am unable to delete any file using `rm` command, and when I use it I get:

```
mv: accessing `/home/user1/.Trash': No such file or directory.
```

How can I re-create the `.Trash` file to be able to delete files?

Comment: try `mkdir ~/.Trash`

Comment: no problem. I want to note that you're not deleting files with that alias, you're just moving them to another directory. is that the intended behaviour? Ubuntu server doesn't use a "trash" by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (re-)create directories with the `mkdir` command. In this case:

```sh
mkdir -m 700 ~/.Trash
```

`-m 700` sets the directory access mode to prohibit access to other users since they shouldn't normally snoop in your trash even if they otherwise share read access to your home directory.

---

Additionally you should probably remove the misleading `rm` alias:

```sh
unalias rm
```

If you want a command to move files to trash like many (graphical) file managers do you can use the `gvfs-trash` application from the `gvfs-bin` package (not installed by default in Ubuntu Server). If that's too long to type for you you can set up an alias similar to this:

```sh
alias trash='gvfs-trash'
```